# Shouldn't this character be infected in The Last of Us II?

Tags: the-last-of-us-2

In The Last of Us Part II there are two separated fights between the two main characters:

> Abby and Ellie.

During the first fight, there's a cut scene where

> Ellie bites Abby in the arm.

From what I understand, Ellie is technically infected, as shown by the scanner in the beginning of part I. She only doesn't turn because of the mutation in her brain, but the infection is there. If this is right, then...

> Shouldn't Abby become infected after Ellie bit her in their first fight?

Answer (score 4):

We don't really know how Ellie's immunity works. However, she does mention:

> I can't... get you infected, if that's what you're worried about... I can't make you immune either.

[image: Last of Us 2 cutscene]

So she somehow knows that she can't infect other people.

Comment: I somehow missed this scene in the game. +1

Comment: I don't know how lesbian relationships work as I'm a white heterosexual male in my late 30s, but...is there a lot of biting involved? Both Abby and Ellie drew blood in their bites, and we know the infection is spread through bites from infected. This is an ok answer, though...

Comment: @tilley31 I don't think that being white or in your 30s disqualifies you from understanding how relationships work!  But the general idea is that the infection is spread through bodily fluids. Whether those fluids need to be saliva and/or blood is unclear, but if so, then most kinds of romantic relationships would include activities that involve the exchange of those fluids. (Think about kissing somebody who has a small cut somewhere in their mouth.) Note that this is already true, even before the zombie apocalypse.

Comment: I was talking about LESBIAN relationships, not all relationships, in a kind of tongue in cheek way :P. Guess the real answer would be wether Ellie qualifies as "infected" or not. As I understand it, she has the infection, but she doesn't turn because of her mutation, which the Fireflies intended to use for a vaccine. If it's not like that, and she just hast the anti-bodies for it, then it's ok.

Comment: @tilley31 I don't think there's a big difference between lesbian relationships and any other kind of relationship when it comes to the issue of whether one partner can infect another with a fungus-based zombie plague. But you're right that we just don't know the details of exactly how the infection works, so we have to take Ellie's word for it that she knows she can't infect other people.